# JS-framework: KineticJS. How is it possible so set variable properties?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

i'm working on a drag&drop-function for images. I've oriented myself on this example here:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/
The JS framework KineticJS is used there.

In this example the properties (`x`,`y`,`width`,`height`) of `Kinetic.Group` and `Kinetic.Image` are set with 'normal' number values.

my problem is that i need this properties as variables, because my uploaded images have different values for `height`, `width` etc.

I've tried to change the code from the example for my own drag&drop web application, but it doesn't work as i want...
I can load and display images correctly, but i can't move or resize them. With number values for `x`,`y`,`width`,`height` it works all.

Here is the code of the changed method "`initStage()`" (the other methods are unchanged):

```
function initStage(images) {
  stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'wb_dropzone',
    width: 500,
    height: 400
  });

  var imageGroups = new Array();
  var imageInstances = new Array();
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  for(var i=0; i<Object.size(images); i++)
  {
    imageGroups[i] = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: fileInfos[i][2][0]/*0*/,
        y: fileInfos[i][2][1]/*0*/,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(imageGroups[i]);

    imageInstances[i] = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0/*fileInfos[i][2][0]*/,
        y: 0/*fileInfos[i][2][1]*/,
        image: images[i],
        width: fileInfos[i][1][0],
        height: fileInfos[i][1][1],
        name: 'image',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        dashArray: [10, 2]
    });

    imageGroups[i].add(imageInstances[i]);
    addAnchor(imageGroups[i], 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(imageGroups[i], fileInfos[i][1][0], 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(imageGroups[i], fileInfos[i][1][0], fileInfos[i][1][1], 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(imageGroups[i], 0, fileInfos[i][1][1], 'bottomLeft');

    imageGroups[i].on('dragstart', function() {
        this.moveToTop();
    });
  }

  stage.add(layer);
  stage.draw();
}
```

More informations about "`fileInfos`":

```
[imagePath, [width, height], [X-pos., Y-pos.]]
```

(all dropped images are uploaded in a folder. The properties of each image are saved in a database.
Default x- and y-position is "0".)

Does anybody have an idea, how i can solve this problem?
I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: Please check the error console and see what errors pop up when you drag the Anchors, and let us know what errors you are getting. From what you're saying, when you use fileInfos you can drag the anchors, but the image doesn't resize at all right? You can definitely use variables for Kinetic object attributes, so my first guess is that maybe you're not accessing `fileInfos` correctly. My second guess is that you have an problem within your loop. It'll really help to see some error logs, to be able to help you further.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I had saved the integer values for width, height etc. als string. I had forgotten to convert this.
Thanks a lot! Now it works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to create draggable/resizable images that are loaded from your fileInfos**

Call a function that creates the group+image+anchors based on your fileInfos[i]:

```
    // pull info supplied by fileInfos for this “i”

    var imgWidth=fileInfos[i][1][0];
    var imgHeight=fileInfos[i][1][1];
    var groupX=fileInfos[i][2][0];
    var groupY=fileInfos[i][2][1];

    // call a function that creates the draggable/resizable group

    addImageGroup( images[i], imgWidth,imgHeight, groupX,groupY );
```

Here’s that function that creates the draggable/resizable group element:

```
  function addImageGroup(image,imageWidth,imageHeight,groupX,groupY){

      // width and height are based on the images width/height
      var w=imageWidth;
      var h=imageHeight;

      var kGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x:groupX,
          y:groupY,
          width:w+20,   // must allow 10+10=20 for anchors
          height:h+20,
          draggable:true
      });
      layer.add(kGroup);

      kGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
      });

      var kImage = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: image,
          width: w,
          height: h,
          name: 'image',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          dashArray: [10, 2]
      });
      kGroup.add(kImage);

      addAnchor(kGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
      addAnchor(kGroup, w, 0, 'topRight');
      addAnchor(kGroup, w, h, 'bottomRight');
      addAnchor(kGroup, 0, h, 'bottomLeft');

  }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/buCzH/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #container{
          border:1px solid red;
          width:350px;
          height:350px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      // create the stage
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 350,
          height: 350
      });
      var layer=new Kinetic.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      // build a test fileInfos array
      // width/height will be gotten from actual images, so leave width/height==0
      var fileInfos=[];
      function addFile(x,y,w,h,imgURL){
          fileInfos.push([imgURL,[w,h],[x,y]]);
      }
      addFile(30,100,102,102,"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-1.jpg");
      addFile(200,100,102,102,"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-3.jpg");

      // load all the images
      var images=[];
      loadAllImages();

      function loadAllImages(){
          var imagesOK=0;
          for (var i = 0; i < fileInfos.length; i++) {
              var img = new Image();
              images.push(img);
              img.onload = function(){ 
                  if (++imagesOK==fileInfos.length ) {

                      // all images are loaded, so build the groups
                      for(var i=0;i<fileInfos.length;i++){
                          var imgWidth=fileInfos[i][1][0];
                          var imgHeight=fileInfos[i][1][1];
                          var groupX=fileInfos[i][2][0];
                          var groupY=fileInfos[i][2][1];
                          addImageGroup( images[i], imgWidth,imgHeight, groupX,groupY );
                      }
                      layer.draw();
                  }
              }; 
              img.src = fileInfos[i][0];
          }      
      }


      function addImageGroup(image,imageWidth,imageHeight,groupX,groupY){

          // width and height are based on the images width/height
          var w=imageWidth;
          var h=imageHeight;

          var kGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
              x:groupX,
              y:groupY,
              width:w+20,   // must allow 10+10=20 for anchors
              height:h+20,
              draggable:true
          });
          layer.add(kGroup);

          kGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
              this.moveToTop();
          });

          var kImage = new Kinetic.Image({
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              image: image,
              width: w,
              height: h,
              name: 'image',
              stroke: 'black',
              strokeWidth: 2,
              dashArray: [10, 2]
          });
          kGroup.add(kImage);

          addAnchor(kGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
          addAnchor(kGroup, w, 0, 'topRight');
          addAnchor(kGroup, w, h, 'bottomRight');
          addAnchor(kGroup, 0, h, 'bottomLeft');

      }


      function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('.image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case 'topLeft':
            topRight.setY(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'topRight':
            topLeft.setY(anchorY);
            bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'bottomRight':
            bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
            topRight.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
          case 'bottomLeft':
            bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
            topLeft.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
        }

        image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
          image.setSize(width, height);
        }
      }


      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: '#666',
          fill: '#ddd',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          this.setStrokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is easier to read than mine. The values ​​in my array had the wrong format. Therefore, it did not work.